# Get forward slash except within square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

Example text (I've highlighted the desired `/`'s):

pair[@Key=2]`/`Items`/`Item[Person/Name='Martin']`/`Date

I'm trying to get each forward slash that isn't within a square bracket, anyone slick with Regex able to help me on this?  The use would be:

```
string[] result = Regex.Split(text, pattern);
```

I've done it with this code, but was wondering if there was a simpler Regex that would do the same thing:

```
private string[] Split()
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    int pos = 0, i = 0;
    bool within = false;
    Func<string> add = () => Format.Substring(pos, i - pos);
    //string a;
    for (; i < Format.Length; i++)
    {
        //a = add();
        char c = Format[i];
        switch (c)
        {
            case '/':
                if (!within)
                {
                    list.Add(add());
                    pos = i + 1;
                }
                break;
            case '[':
                within = true;
                break;
            case ']':
                within = false;
                break;
        }
    }
    list.Add(add());
    return list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `Regex.Matches` might be a better approach than trying to use split.  Instead of specifying a pattern to split on, you try to match your desired outputs.  This works in basic cases:

```
string[] FancySplit(string input) {
    return Regex.Matches(input, @"([^/\[\]]|\[[^]]*\])+")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Value)
        .ToArray();
}
```

The approach of the regular expression is to look for a sequence of:

- characters that are not `[`, `]`, or `/`

  or
- A sequence of the form `[` something `]`, where something is allowed to contain `/`

Answer (score 2):

This will not work for general case, but it will do most practical cases right:

```
(?<!\[[^]]+)/
```

This expression uses a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to match a forward slash unless it is preceded by a square bracket followed by a sequence of characters other than a closing square bracket.

Comment: To clarify what "practical cases" means for this answer, this regex will work as long as you can't "nest" square brackets.  If you can do something like this: `asdf[123[456] \ ]jkl` then this answer won't work.

Comment: @Servy You are absolutely right: if you are to allow nesting brackets, regexp-based solutions would not be theoretically possible, for the same reason it is not possible to write a regexp telling strings with balanced parentheses from strings with unbalanced parentheses.

Comment: This works thank you - but I may go with @recursive 's solution

Comment: @ChuckSavage I know what you mean - I just upvoted his solution :)